# C POSIX - aio_read, aio_write checking file contents and replacing non alpha-numeric characters

Tags: c, linux, posix, aio

[EDIT - 06.01.2020]

I am trying to write a program which will do asynchronous I/O. The program takes 2 parameters: the filename f and the number of blocks n. The file size must be divided into n blocks of equal size and the reminder part of the file R. Program starts asynchronous read operation for each block in turn. The AIO read operation must start the thread on the completion. The thread must replace all not alphabetical characters in the currently processed block with spaces, then the thread should write the block synchronously at the same position in the file and terminate. After processing all the n blocks the program must process the R part of the file in the same way.

What I have - :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void error(char *);
void usage(char *);
void siginthandler(int);
void sethandler(void (*)(int), int);
off_t getfilelength(int);
void fillaiostructs(struct aiocb *, int, int, int, char **);
void suspend(struct aiocb *, int);
void readdata(struct  aiocb *, int);
void writedata(struct aiocb *, off_t);
void syncdata(struct aiocb *, int);
void getindexes(int *, int);
void cleanup(char **, int);
void reversebuffer(char *, int);
void processblocks(struct aiocb *, char **, int, int, int);
volatile sig_atomic_t work;

void error(char *msg){
  perror(msg);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void usage(char *progname){
  fprintf(stderr, "%s workfile blocksize\n", progname);
  fprintf(stderr, "workfile - path to the file to work on\n");
  fprintf(stderr, "n - number of blocks\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

off_t getfilelength(int fd){
  struct stat buf;
  if (fstat(fd, &buf) == -1) {
    error("Fstat on the file failed!");
  }
  return buf.st_size;
}

void fileinfo(int fd) {
  struct stat buf;
  if(fstat(fd, &buf) == -1) {
    error("Fstat on the file failed!");
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "Total file length: %ld \n \n", buf.st_size);

}

void suspend(struct aiocb * aiocbs, int blocks) {
  struct aiocb * aiolist[blocks];
  for(int k=0; k<blocks; k++) {
    aiolist[k] = &aiocbs[k];
  }
  while(aio_suspend((const struct aiocb *const *) aiolist, blocks, NULL) == -1) {
    if(errno == EINTR) continue;
    error("SUSPEND ERROR!");
  }
  if(aio_error(aiocbs) != 0) {
    error("SUSPEND ERROR!");
  }
  if(aio_return(aiocbs) == -1) {
    error("RETURN ERROR!");
  }
}

void syncdata(struct aiocb * aiocbs, int blocks) {
  suspend(aiocbs, blocks);
  if (aio_fsync(O_SYNC, aiocbs) == -1) {
    error("ERROR SYNC! \n");
  }
}

void readdata(struct aiocb  * aiocbs, int val) {
  if(aio_read(&aiocbs[val]) == -1){
    error("ERROR aio_read!");
  }
}

void operate(union sigval sv) {

  struct aiocb * aio;
  aio = sv.sival_ptr;
  //char * s = sv.sival_ptr;
  fprintf(stderr, "Thread [%ld] working \n", pthread_self());
  char * s = (void *) aio->aio_buf;
  for(int i=0; i<sizeof(s); i++) {
    if(isalnum(s[i]) || s[i] == '\n') {
      continue;
    }
    else s[i] = ' ';
  }

  if(write(aio->aio_fildes, s, aio->aio_nbytes) != aio->aio_nbytes) {
    error("ERROR sync write!");
  }

}

void fillaiostructs(struct aiocb *aiocbs, int fd, int blocksize, int blocks, char ** buffer){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<blocks; i++){
      memset(&aiocbs[i], 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));
      aiocbs[i].aio_fildes = fd;
      if (i==0) aiocbs[i].aio_offset = 0;
      else aiocbs[i].aio_offset = aiocbs[i-1].aio_offset+blocksize;
      aiocbs[i].aio_nbytes = blocksize;
      aiocbs[i].aio_buf = (void *) buffer[i];
      aiocbs[i].aio_sigevent.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
      aiocbs[i].aio_sigevent.sigev_notify_function = &operate;
      aiocbs[i].aio_sigevent.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &aiocbs[i];
}

}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int blocksize, blocks, fd, R;
  char * filename;

  if(argc != 3) {
    usage(argv[0]);
  }

  blocks = atoi(argv[2]);
  filename = argv[1];

  if ((fd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(open(filename, O_RDWR))) == -1) {
      error("Cannot open file!");
  }

  blocksize = (getfilelength(fd) -1) / blocks;
  R = getfilelength(fd) - blocks * blocksize;

  fileinfo(fd);

  struct aiocb aiocbs[blocks];
  char *buffer[blocks];
  // Allocating memory for i=number of blocks for the buffer
  for (int i = 0; i<=blocks; i++) {
    if ((buffer[i] = (char *) calloc (blocksize, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
      error("Cannot allocate memory for the buffer!");
    }
  }

  fillaiostructs(aiocbs, fd, blocksize, blocks, buffer);

  for(int i=0; i<blocks; i++)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Block: %d | Offset: %ld | Size: %ld \n", i, aiocbs[i].aio_offset, aiocbs[i].aio_nbytes);
    readdata(aiocbs, i);
    sleep(1);
  }
syncdata(aiocbs, blocks);

[...]
freeing memory, cleanup
[...]

}
```

Now it looks like the input is processed correctly - the content is synchronously written to the file with all non alphanumeric characters changed to spaces but I am concerned with the usage of sleep(1) in the main thread after scheduling each aio_read.
I also added aios_fsync, aio_suspend with some error checking.

My question is: is the sleep(1) or other form of waiting/suspending in the main thread necessary? Or maybe there are other errors which force me to use sleep()?

Comment: The `<ctype.h>` header will be useful for telling if a character is alphabetic or not.

Comment: Please fix indentation in your code - it's inconsistent. Note that there is already a [error](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html) function in GNU. I don't understand your code. How do you synchronize the execution of aio callback with freeing the buffers? Don't you worry you could free the buffers before aio operation is executed? You can pass custom data to the new thread using `sival_ptr` in `sigevent`. But your code really does nothing, you don't even call `aio_return` on any of the aio operations. All of them could have failed.

Comment: You are passing the address of a auto variable in `readdata` to `aio_read`, you should pass a pointer to some `aiocb` data to `aio_read`, then later you could call `aio_fsync` to synchronize and `aio_return` to get the count. Right now your code just queries some aio operations without caring if they ever succeed or not or what happens to them. And `check and replace non alphabetical characters etc` - so check or replace? What exactly? What do you mean by etc? What exactly should your code produce? Should it edit the file? Output something?

Comment: Thanks for some suggestions. The code should check for non alphabetical characters and replace them with spaces and write it to the file as in the  description: "The thread must replace all not alphabetical characters in the currently processed block with spaces, then the thread should write the block synchronously at the same position in the file and terminate."

Comment: @KamilCuk I followed your suggestions and I improved the code. Now it seems to work but I suppose it is still not correct. I edited the question with the new code and new problem that has arisen.

Comment: `i<sizeof(s);`, the `sizeof(s)` is a size of a char pointer, it's `sizeof(char*)`, that's invalid. Do `ssize_t ret = aio_return(&aio); if (ret == -1) { printf("It failed"); } size_t number_of_bytes_readed = ret;`